# Averaging data at specific hours across days in R

Tags: r, time-series, average, xts

- Update(2021/5/13, 11:55AM): The data is not reproducible. Thank you @G. Grothendieck for giving me a comment.

(This is my first post in Stackoverflow, so please let me know if there's any basic mistakes I made in this question)

Hi,

I have a hourly-measured data of air quality over multiple days in R, and I would like to calculate the average air quality at specific time periods.

Here's a subset of my reproducible data. It is in xts format.

```r
# Make a structure of data
dput(Air_sample[1:6,1:1])

# Create a data from the structure above.
Air <- structure(
 c(2.6, 2, 2.2, 2.2, 1.6, 1.2),
 class = c("xts", "zoo"),
 index = structure(
  c(
   1078959600,
   1078963200,
   1079046000,
   1079049600,
   1079132400,
   1079136000
  ),
  tzone = "",
  tclass = c("POSIXct",
             "POSIXt")
 ),
 .Dim = c(6L, 1L),
 .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("True.CO")))

> Air
                    True.CO
2004-03-10 18:00:00     2.6
2004-03-10 19:00:00     2.0
2004-03-11 18:00:00     2.2
2004-03-11 19:00:00     2.2
2004-03-12 18:00:00     1.6
2004-03-12 19:00:00     1.2
```

I want to calculate average CO at specific time (ex. 6PM) from multiple days.
So the result would be something like below.

```r
Air_average <- data.frame("Time" = c("18:00","19:00"), "Average CO" = c(2.1333,1.8))

> Air_average
   Time Average.CO
1 18:00     2.1333
2 19:00     1.8000
```

I tried different function via Googling such as "period.apply", "subset", "window", etc. But none of them seems to work.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please show the exact input for an example and the corresponding output.  Do not use dot dot dot.    Also use dput as asked for at the top of the [tag:r] tag page to show the data in reproducible form and ensure that the output does correspond to the input exactly.  It is also not at all clear what you want. The question says you want the average for 6:00 but the output shows other times.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thank you for your comment. I am reading posts and watching videos of how to use dput to properly post here. I will update this post shortly.

Comment: Probably ``aggregate`` will do the job. But I can't remember the syntax.

Comment: @Jeremy Thank you. I tried aggregate and somehow found a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like `dplyr` to do grouping operation, and `lubridate` to deal with dates. `lubridate` has the `hour` function which return only the hours.
I first convert your data into a data frame:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(xts)

Air <- data.frame(Air) %>% 
  add_rownames(var = "time")

  time                True.CO
  <chr>                 <dbl>
1 2004-03-11 00:00:00     2.6
2 2004-03-11 01:00:00     2  
3 2004-03-12 00:00:00     2.2
4 2004-03-12 01:00:00     2.2
5 2004-03-13 00:00:00     1.6
6 2004-03-13 01:00:00     1.2
```

Because of my timezone, the hours are not the same than yours, but the code will be the same.

```
Air %>%
  group_by(hour(time))%>%
  summarise(mean(True.CO))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  `hour(time)` `mean(True.CO)`
         <int>           <dbl>
1            0            2.13
2            1            1.8
```

Comment: No pb. There are a lot of option to do grouping operation: `tapply` in base R, you can also have a look at `data.table`, which is very powerfull. But `dplyr` is by far the most used